# Database not creating

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, vaadin

I just started to use vaadin. I'm currently using the H2 database, but when I want to create the database "Upload" I get an error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table upload (id varchar(255) not null, file_name varchar(255) not null, import_date bigint not null, month varchar(255) not null, year varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:442) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
```

I created like in the tutorial the Repository and the Service Class dedicated to the Upload Table.

Comment: How is this related to Vaadin? Does it work if you remove Vaadin?

Comment: Im using it in Vaadin so yeah even if its working outside of vaadin it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: So _does_ it work without vaadin and vaadin is the sole culprit? I find that hard to believe and i think, this is mistagged. The error suggest a error with the used SQL, which more likely suggest a mis-configuration in H2, Hibernate, or the migrations within.

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace. There must be a SQL exception indicating what's wrong

Comment: I dont know its the only issue. The other Databases over H2, Spring and Vaadin are working perfectly fine.

Comment: The full stacktrace: [link](https://hastebin.com/ohejabogil.properties)
Cant post it here because its too long for the comment section

Comment: You are probably having field in your entity which has name which is reserved keyword in the database you use, or you have slightly wrong database driver / dialect setup in your project. In case of first one use  `@Column` to define the actual column name in your entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MONTH and YEAR are reserved keywords in H2 and the SQL standard.

You have to rename the attributes or only the column with `@Column` annotation.

Please find the full list here:
http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html